# Formula conversion from Google Sheets to Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, export-to-excel

I am using 2 formulas for finding only duplicate values and listing them in another sheet. But when I downloaded the Spreadsheet as Microsoft Excel (xlsx), QUERY formula and Array function dont work on Microsoft Excel.

So I need your help about Microsoft Excel.

This is my formulas using on Google Sheets. How can I do that on Microsoft Excel? I am open to another formulas or solutions.

`=INDEX( QUERY( QUERY( {'DATA'!A2:A}, "SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col1) GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY Count(Col1) DESC"),  "WHERE Col2 > 1",0) ,,1)`

Test sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QJ7OLlrDg_9cZjwZFXjVFo0NHB6QvHl8MszQTYf4w2I/edit#gid=1428898146

Comment: You have to find other functions to replace the ones that don't work, OR you have to work from the logic that you used to build your Googlesheets formula to repeat that logic with excel functions.

Comment: @SolarMike Do you know which function on Excel gives me the only duplicate values? I dont know. So I am asking.

Comment: FILTER with COUNTIF(S) or with MMULT. It's better to post some sample data and it's expected result

Comment: @P.b How can I do that with Array? Because second sheet should be dynamic. If I add a value in Data sheet, it should be counted (and added if duplicate) automatically in second sheet.

Comment: @P.b https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QJ7OLlrDg_9cZjwZFXjVFo0NHB6QvHl8MszQTYf4w2I/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 2):

With your shared example:

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(DATA!A:A,COUNTIF(DATA!A:A,DATA!A:A)>1))`

But this will be real slow, because it calculates each row of column A, also the empty ones.

To workaround we can use:

```
=LET(data,FILTER(DATA!A:A,DATA!A:A<>""),
     u,   UNIQUE(data),
FILTER(u, MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(data)=u),SEQUENCE(ROWS(data),,1,0))>1))
```

In this case we can't use COUNTIF, because this requires a range, but using LET converts it to array. Therefore MMULT can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming data has a header, you can also use frequency:

```
=LET(data,DROP(TOCOL(Data!A:A,1),1),
u,UNIQUE(data),
f,DROP(FREQUENCY(data,u),-1),
HSTACK(FILTER(u,f>1),FILTER(f,f>1)))
```

[image]

If hstack is not available, you can try:

```
=LET(data,DROP(TOCOL(Data!A:A,1),1),
u,UNIQUE(data),
f,DROP(FREQUENCY(data,u),-1),
CHOOSE({1,2},FILTER(u,f>1),FILTER(f,f>1)))
```